# Is possible to write mysql query inside the init.js

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I having init.js page like this

```
function fnFormatDetails ( oTable, nTr )
{
    var aData = oTable.fnGetData( nTr );
    var sOut = '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">';
    sOut += '<tr><td>Rendering engine:</td><td>'+aData[1]+' '+aData[4]+'</td></tr>';
    sOut += '<tr><td>Link to source:</td><td>Could provide a link here</td></tr>';
    sOut += '<tr><td>Extra info:</td><td>And any further details here (images etc)</td></tr>';
    sOut += '</table>';

    return sOut;
}
```

What I want is to write a mySql query that retrieves data from the database and shows it `sOut` in js

Is it possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Change the file extension to `.php`
**Step 2:** Change the header content-type to `text/javascript`:

```
<?php
   // put it before any other code even before a line break or a space
   header("Content-type: text/javascript");
?>
```

**Step 3:** You can use `js` and `php` code together.

**Note:** To include it use the filename with `.php` extension:

```
<script src="init.php"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not possible at all use php file to write PHP and JavaScript together.